# Suddenly crashed httpd service not starting again

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6

I have a local server running CentOS 6.4 and Apache 2.2.15 ... Couple of days back my apache crashed and didn't start ever since ... I have tried reinstall through YUM and even tried removing and installing it from scratch but I have having the same issue ... here is a screenshot of the error when I try to start the httpd service.

[Terminal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Si4u.png)

Can anyone guide me through this problem ... thanks.

Regards,
Faisal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check your logs to get more information. On CentOS the default location for the error log is `/var/log/httpd`. You should look at the error_log for any relevant messages and take appropriate action. Remember google is your friend when taking appropriate initial action.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check Apache main file:

```
sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Check, the module load call exist in this file:

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
```

Also check the php.conf file:

```
sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf
```

Check, module load call also exist here, so to fix this warning, we’ll comment/remove the module load call here:

```
#LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
```

Restart the httpd service:

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

Comment: There was no call for the `php5_module` in the httpd.conf but there was this in the `php.conf` and I commented it `<IfModule prefork.c>
 LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
</IfModule>` ... I have tried to restart the httpd service but still the same error as shown in the screenshot in the question.